# Creating the new .eap file

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

We have created the EA addin using C#. In this We have the windows form in which we have created new model project button. When the user clicks the button we want to create the new .eap file and add the package to it form C# program

Answer (score 0):

What EA does to create a new EAP is simply making a copy of EABase.eap in EA's program folder.

Comment: So how can i create this .eap file from the customized windows form in C#. Which method should I override to create it in EA class.

Comment: Just use any copy equivalent method from the OS for files.

Comment: yes i am able to create the .eap file at the particular location i have given but it is not getting reflected in the project browser.So how to reflect the created .eap file in the project browser of the EA

Comment: Copy it to some location. Then open this file with Repository.OpenFile (string <some location>)